# How to send method to view from action called by UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I understand (I think) why this isn't working, but I don't know how to get it to work.

I have a method I call in `viewWillAppear` like so (I've simplified the code for the sake of this question):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
        [self displayHour:0];
}
```

I then have a little for loop that builds some buttons in `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSUInteger b = 0;

for (UIButton *hourButton in hourButtons) {
    [hourButton setTag:b];
    [hourButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)b] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [hourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showHour:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    b++;
}
```

Then for the action I have this:

```
- (IBAction)showHour:(id)sender
{
        // Logs 0, 1, etc. depending on which button is tapped
    NSLog(@"Button tag is: %lu", (long int)[sender tag]); 

    // This currently throws this error:
    // No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'displayHour:'

    // What I want to do is be able to call this method on
    // the main view and pass along the button tag of the 
    // button that was tapped.
    [mainView displayHour:(long int)[sender tag]];
}
```

**THE QUESTION** is how do I call `displayHour` to the main view from the `showHour:` action?

If you need it, the displayHour method looks like this (simplified, basically updates some labels and image views on the main view):

```
- (void)displayHour:(NSUInteger)i
{    
    // The temperature
    hourTemp = [[hourly objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"temperature"];

    // The icon
    hourIcon = [[hourly objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"icon"];

    // The precipitation
    hourPrecip = [[hourly objectAtIndex:i] valueForKeyPath:@"precipProbability"];

    // SET DISPLAY
    [hourTempField setText:hourTemp];
    [hourIconFrame setImage:hourIcon];
    [hourPrecipField setText:hourPrecip];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is mainView ? if this is pointing to same object then use self. if it is the object of any other class than its fine. I think method is in same class. So please use self to call method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
   [mainView displayHour:(long int)[sender tag]];
```

do:

```
   [self displayHour:(long int)[sender tag]];
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks. See @C_X's comment on the original question as well.